# POST value is empty when Sending POST request with Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: php, post, postman

I have sent the POST Request with header Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded via postman.

I get the `$_POST` array in PHP as the following format. I can't able to access the `$_POST` in a PHP page. How do I resolve this?

```
<?php 
switch($method)
{
    case 'registration':
        print_r($_POST);exit;
    break;
}
?>
```

Result is

```
Array
    (
        [------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "fname"

    bala
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lname"

    ba
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uname"

    stsbsathish
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"

    chennai
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

    stsbsath2@gmail.com
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

    12345
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city"

    3
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="state"

    7
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

    8
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"

    897973487
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="term"

    1
    ------WebKitFormBoundarydUQfNkeuyFTIFgMo--

    )
```

Comment: How does the body look in postman?

Comment: form-data @Ferrybig

Comment: refer this question, [How to get response of content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded by passing parameters in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227695/how-to-get-response-of-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-by-passing/64229384)

Answer (score 0):

Note the header `Content-Type` should be: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` rather use `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Comment: enctype is working, but how can I get POST array while using Content-type?? is there any solution??